# CSV in hashtable then calculate sum

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, hashtable

this is my csv file :

```
name;value
John;4.0
John;-15.0
John;1.0
John;-2.0
Bob;1.0
Bob;2.5
Bob;-8
```

I want to print this output :

```
John : 22
Bob : 11,5
```

**22 because 4+15+1+2=22**

**11,5 because 1+2,5+8 = 11,5**

It's important to ignore the `-` sign and calculate the total with positive sign.

I tried this :

```
import csv
with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        print row
Hashtable = {}
```

I know I have to use hashtable with key value system, but i'm stuck at this point, please help me, i'm using python 2.7.

Comment: create john and bob variables equal to zero, as you loop you can do if row[0]=='John': john+=abs(row[1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming `11,5` should be `11.5`, use a `defaultdict` to handle repeated keys, just `str.lstrip` any minus sign and `+=` each value

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(float)
with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    next(reader) # skip header
    for name, val in reader:
        d[name] += float(val.lstrip("-"))
```

Output:

```
for k,v in d.items():
    print(k,v)
('Bob', 11.5)
('John', 22.0)
```

If you wanted to use a regular dict for some reason you can use `dict.setdefault`:

```
d = {}
with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)
    for name, val in reader:
        d.setdefault(name, 0)
        d[name] += float(val.lstrip("-"))
```

Using the defauldict and lstrip is the most efficient, some timings:

```
In [26]: timeit default()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.6 ms per loop

In [27]: timeit counter()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.98 ms per loop
```

Comment: Why `for row in reader: name, val = row` instead of `for name, val in reader`? Personal preference?

Comment: @jme, not really, originally I was doing  something else, just overlooked it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can adjust your code to output a hash at the end :

```
import csv
out_hash = {}
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
  reader.next() # Just to skip the header
  for row in reader:
    if row[0] in out_hash:
      out_hash[row[0]] += abs(float(row[1]))
    else:
      out_hash[row[0]] = abs(float(row[1]))
print out_hash
```

Output:

```
{'Bob': 11.5, 'John': 22.0}
```

Comment: `row[0] in out_hash.keys()` is and `O(n)` operation so you are making the code highly inefficient this defeating the purpoe

Comment: @PadraicCunningham .keys() was definitely wrong but the updated code checking only through the hash not an array of the keys has almost O(1).

Answer (score 1):

I would use Counter in this case, which is a standard library wrapper around a dictionary that allows you to count elements easily.

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter()

with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    reader.next() #skips the heading
    for row in reader:
        counter[row[0]] += abs(float(row[1]))
```

Now, if you actually need to use the vanilla dictionary, then you would simply need to bloat your counting logic up a bit, i.e. instead of

```
counter[row[0]] += abs(float(row[1]))
```

do

```
my_dict = {}
...
if row[0] not in my_dict:
    my_dict[row[0]] = abs(float(row[1]))
else
    my_dict += abs(float(row[1]))
```

Comment: You are not counting you are summing so there is no advantage to using a Counter dict

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Sure. I didn't know defaultdict defaulted to 0. So always used counter to lose the lambda. Thanks, I learnt something new!

Comment: It's not so much that `defaultdict` defaults to zero as it is that `float()` defaults to zero.

Comment: Fair enough. Stupid me. I see now.